# Bind variables in the from clause for Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables

I'm attempting to write an extension for SQL Developer to better support Postgres. These are just XML configuration files with SQL snippets in them. To display the values for a postgres sequence, I need to run a simple query of the following form:

```
select * from schema.sequence
```

The trouble with this is that the Oracle SQL Developer environment provides the correct schema and node (sequence) name as bind variables. This would mean that I should format the query as:

```
select * from :SCHEMA.:NAME
```

The trouble with this is that bind variables are only valid in the select clause or the where clause (as far as I'm aware), and using this form of the query returns a `"syntax error at or near "$1"` error message.

Is there a way to return the values in the sequence object without directly selecting them from the sequence? Perhaps some obtuse joined statement from pg_catalog tables?

Comment: You could use dynamic SQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-dynamic.html

Comment: @Nicarus I thought about execute immediate, but at least in Oracle you can't run select statements with it. I didn't see anything that made PG seem different in that regard. Guess I was looking at the wrong page.

Comment: You *can* use `execute immediate` to run a select statement, but then you can't return a result set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * 
from information_schema.sequences 
where sequence_name = :name 
  and sequence_schema = :schema;
```

It's not exactly the same thing as doing a select from the sequence, but the basic information is there.

Comment: You could also do a `psql -E` and see the SQL behind `\d sequence_name`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I knew it must be available like that somehow, but I'm still learning my away around the PG schemas and tables.